# Visual Studio 2017 reports this error for my multi-platform xamarin App

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, xamarin.forms

Someone Help I have been on this issue for 4 days, my app was working perfectly fine when it started reporting this error "This debug engine does not support exception conditions. The condition(s) will be ignored". It does not find some of the dll.so packages, I tried deleting the bin and debug folder, and rebuild the App, I have also reinstalled and installed visual studio, formatted my PC and did a clean installation all to no avail. The same comes up, when I try running the same app from different user in the project Repo in gitlab. I tried different emulators and now using my phone but still mp solution.

[image]

```js
This debug engine does not support exception conditions. The condition(s) will be ignored.
03-04 23:59:08.480 E/Zygote  (32704): v2
03-04 23:59:08.480 I/SELinux (32704): Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_SM-G903W_5.1.1 ver=51
03-04 23:59:08.480 W/SELinux (32704): Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], priority [2], priority version is VE=SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1_0033
03-04 23:59:08.480 E/Zygote  (32704): accessInfo : 0
03-04 23:59:08.480 W/SELinux (32704): SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.companyname.CHA 
03-04 23:59:08.480 I/art     (32704): Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-04 23:59:08.480 I/libpersona(32704): KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10006
03-04 23:59:08.480 I/libpersona(32704): KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
03-04 23:59:08.530 D/TimaKeyStoreProvider(32704): TimaSignature is unavailable
03-04 23:59:08.530 D/ActivityThread(32704): Added TimaKeyStore provider
03-04 23:59:08.590 D/ResourcesManager(32704): For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
03-04 23:59:08.760 W/monodroid(32704): Creating public update directory: `/data/user/0/com.companyname.CHA/files/.__override__`
03-04 23:59:08.760 W/monodroid(32704): Using override path: /data/user/0/com.companyname.CHA/files/.__override__
03-04 23:59:08.760 W/monodroid(32704): Using override path: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.CHA/files/.__override__
03-04 23:59:08.760 W/monodroid(32704): Trying to load sgen from: /data/user/0/com.companyname.CHA/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
03-04 23:59:08.760 W/monodroid(32704): Trying to load sgen from: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.CHA/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
03-04 23:59:08.760 W/monodroid(32704): Trying to load sgen from: /storage/emulated/0/../legacy/Android/data/com.companyname.CHA/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
03-04 23:59:08.760 W/monodroid(32704): Trying to load sgen from: /data/app/com.companyname.CHA-1/lib/arm/libmonosgen-2.0.so
03-04 23:59:08.770 W/monodroid(32704): Trying to load sgen from: /data/user/0/com.companyname.CHA/files/.__override__/links/libmonosgen-2.0.so
03-04 23:59:08.780 W/monodroid-debug(32704): Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:29210,server=y,embedding=1
03-04 23:59:08.820 W/monodroid-debug(32704): Accepted stdout connection: 23
03-04 23:59:09.610 D/Mono    (32704): Image addref mscorlib[0xea2d09e0] -> mscorlib.dll[0xee999600]: 2
03-04 23:59:09.620 D/Mono    (32704): Prepared to set up assembly 'mscorlib' (mscorlib.dll)
03-04 23:59:09.620 D/Mono    (32704): AOT: image 'mscorlib.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.companyname.CHA-1/lib/arm/libaot-mscorlib.dll.so" not found
03-04 23:59:09.620 D/Mono    (32704): AOT: image '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-9/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-armeabi-v7a-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/mscorlib.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.companyname.CHA-1/lib/arm/libaot-mscorlib.dll.so" not found
03-04 23:59:09.620 D/Mono    (32704): Config attempting to parse: 'mscorlib.dll.config'.
03-04 23:59:09.620 D/Mono    (32704): Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-9/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-armeabi-v7a-release/etc/mono/assemblies/mscorlib/mscorlib.config'.
03-04 23:59:09.670 D/Mono    (32704): Assembly mscorlib[0xea2d09e0] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
03-04 23:59:11.940 D/Mono    (32704): Assembly Loader probing location: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.CHA/files/.__override__/CHA.Android.dll'.
03-04 23:59:11.940 D/Mono    (32704): Image addref CHA.Android[0xea2d0bc0] -> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.CHA/files/.__override__/CHA.Android.dll[0xea427500]: 2
03-04 23:59:11.940 D/Mono    (32704): Prepared to set up assembly 'CHA.Android' (/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.CHA/files/.__override__/CHA.Android.dll)
03-04 23:59:11.940 D/Mono    (32704): Assembly CHA.Android[0xea2d0bc0] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
03-04 23:59:11.940 D/Mono    (32704): AOT: image '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.CHA/files/.__override__/CHA.Android.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.companyname.CHA-1/lib/arm/libaot-CHA.Android.dll.so" not found
03-04 23:59:11.940 D/Mono    (32704): AOT: image '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-9/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-armeabi-v7a-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/CHA.Android.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.companyname.CHA-1/lib/arm/libaot-CHA.Android.dll.so" not found
03-04 23:59:11.940 D/Mono    (32704): Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.CHA/files/.__override__/CHA.Android.dll'.
03-04 23:59:11.940 D/Mono    (32704): Config attempting to parse: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.CHA/files/.__override__/CHA.Android.dll.config'.
03-04 23:59:11.940 D/Mono    (32704): Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-9/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-armeabi-v7a-release/etc/mono/assemblies/CHA.Android/CHA.Android.config'.
03-04 23:59:11.940 D/Mono    (32704): Assembly Loader probing location: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.CHA/files/.__override__/BottomNavigationBar.dll'.
03-04 23:59:11.940 D/Mono    (32704): Image addref BottomNavigationBar[0xea2d0aa0] -> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.CHA/files/.__override__/BottomNavigationBar.dll[0xea427a00]: 2
03-04 23:59:11.940 D/Mono    (32704): Prepared to set up assembly 'BottomNavigationBar' (/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.CHA/files/.__override__/BottomNavigationBar.dll)
03-04 23:59:11.940 D/Mono    (32704): Assembly BottomNavigationBar[0xea2d0aa0] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
03-04 23:59:11.940 D/Mono    (32704): AOT: image '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.CHA/files/.__override__/BottomNavigationBar.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.companyname.CHA-1/lib/arm/libaot-BottomNavigationBar.dll.so" not found
03-04 23:59:11.940 D/Mono    (32704): AOT: image '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-9/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-armeabi-v7a-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/BottomNavigationBar.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.companyname.CHA-1/lib/arm/libaot-BottomNavigationBar.dll.so" not found
03-04 23:59:11.940 D/Mono    (32704): Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.CHA/files/.__override__/BottomNavigationBar.dll'.
03-04 23:59:11.950 D/Mono    (32704): Config attempting to parse: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.CHA/files/.__override__/BottomNavigationBar.dll.config'.
03-04 23:59:11.950 D/Mono    (32704): Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d1
```

Comment: Make sure your SDK components are updated. There may be issue with the emulator image.

Comment: Does a blank new app work?

Comment: Did you update your Visual studio before?

Comment: @LupusOssorum A blank app works perfectly fine

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I did no update to visual studio when I started getting the error

Comment: @Jaymin All my sdk components are up to date

Comment: Try to run an application in the real device instead of the emulator and check.

Comment: @Jaymin I have tried running the the app on my android phone and still  gets same error

Comment: Something in your code or files is probably causing the problem.  Fun, I know, but try rebuilding your app by coping over the code to the blank template piece by piece and see at what point it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem went away after closing Visual Studio, deleting the `obj` and build folders, and then building again. Using the clean and rebuild options in Visual Studio didn't work, so it seems Xamarin in Visual Studio doesn't do a proper clean/rebuild.

This was a major waste of time since it started with breakpoints just not being hit when I expected them to without knowing why. The message `This debug engine does not support exception conditions. The condition(s) will be ignored.` is very easy to miss because there is a lot of noise in the log during startup.